# Limit superior of sum of sequences proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim s_n = s$ and $\limsup t_n = t$.
>
> Prove that $\limsup s_n + t_n = s + t$

Proof (can someone please verify it?):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Then, $\exists N_1$ such that $\forall n > N_1$, $s_n < s + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Also, $\exists N_2$ such that $\forall n > N_2$, $t_n < t + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Now, $\forall n > $ max$\{N_1, N_2\}$, $s_n+t_n < s+t+\epsilon$

So, $\limsup s_n+t_n \leq s+t$

There exists a subsequence $(t_{n_k})$ of $(t_n)$ converging to $t$. Then, $\lim (s_{n_k} + t_{n_k}) = s + t$.

Let $\delta > 0$. Then, $\exists N_0$ such that $\forall k > N_0, s_{n_k}+t_{n_k} > s + t - \delta$. So, $\limsup s_n+t_n \geq s+t$

Therefore, $\limsup s_n+t_n = s+t$

Comment: This is correct. Well done.